# how to access a iframe hidden div tag from its parent window

Tags: iframe, html, tags, hidden

> when i click on a button in parent window a pop up which is in hidden div tag must be displayed in the iframe that is loaded in the page....i dont understand where i have gone wrong so please help me out

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>The iframe</title>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
return false;
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<div id="popup"style="visibility:hidden;"><strong><h1>POPUP</strong></h1>
<A 
   HREF="inframe.html" 
   onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')">click me</A>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: function showPopup()
{
var iframe = window.frames[0].document.getElementById('myFrame');
var childtag = iframe.getElementById('popup');
if (childtag) 
{
childtag.style=(childtag.style=='hidden')?'visible':'hidden';
}
} this is my code in parent window....nothing is happening when i run this code pls help me out....